# Dagesh lene in קדּשנו

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk

When we say the blessing on commandments, such as Tefillin, there is a dagesh in the דּ of קדּשנו.

From what I have learnt a dagesh lene occurs when the בגד כפת starts a syllable and is not preceded by a vowel.

In קדּשנו the ק takes a vowel and breaks this rule. Is the dagesh in this instance a forte?

Comment: Definitely doubled. qiddeshanu is correct, not qidshanu. Syrian and Iraqi Jews are very particular about this.

Answer (score 5):

You have this one basically figured out. The dagesh there is indeed a dagesh forte, and thus the /d/ sound is to be geminated.

This word is in the Pi'el form and, generally speaking, Pi'el verbs take a dagesh forte in the middle consonant when possible.